# Mac "show desktop" logs me out and restarts applications

Tags: macos, display, hot-corner

I have set my macbook (OSX 10.10.3) to use the upper right corner of my display as a hot corner to show the desk top. Recently when I move my mouse to the upper right corner of the screen it does not reveal the desktop, but instead it logs me out entirely and displays a login screen. When I log back in, I find all of my applications are restarting.

[image]

The only thing I can think that might be causing this issue is that I've recently installed a display driver so I could use a 3rd screen but I'm not exactly sure how to test to identify for sure if that is the culprit or not. Is there anything else that might cause this? Is there anyway to fix it?

I know I can see the desktop by pressing F11 on the keyboard, and that works fine, but I'd like to try and fix this because I'm suspicious that it might be part of a bigger problem. Does anyone know what the deal is here? Other hot corners work as intended.

**UPDATE:** I have been using the F11 key until I could find an answer to this question, but now the F11 key is logging me out as well. It seems any time I need to see the desktop I risk losing all the work I've been doing and getting kicked out by the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a work around for this problem. The issue is caused when the user is running displays off of a 3rd party USB display adaptor that uses the DisplayLink drivers. The work around is easy but involves sacrificing some of your display animations (which is totally worth it to me personally). Here's a link to the article where I found the answer:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5679540

And here are the two commands that you need to run in terminal to turn off the display animations:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0
killall Dock
```

That's it! Just run those two little commands and you're solid. Been testing it out and haven't had any problems yet. I'll update this if I encounter any more unintended log outs.